# How to call devenv.com in powershell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I just want to run the following two lines.

```
cd SomeDirectory
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com 
   Source\MySolution.sln /build Release /project Source\My\Setup\Project.vdproj
```

If I wrap everything in quotes, nothing seems to happen other than the strings printing to the console.

Answer (score 5):

When quoting a path to a program to run it you need to prepend `&`:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" Source\MySolution.sln /build Release /project Source\My\Setup\Project.vdproj"
```

The reason being that PowerShell has two different parsing modes: command mode and expression mode. But the quoted string will switch to expression mode, thus you explicitly need the *call operator*, `&`.

Another thing: You may have to use a full path for the arguments because PowerShell has a different notion of a current directory, that native programs don't share.

Comment: How to include the full path with "" in Source\MySolution.sln ?

Comment: @Yiping: You surround it with quotes if necessary. Note that PowerShell will still parse arguments and quote arguments to external programs based on its own rules. Using `--%` (cf. `Get-Help about_parsing`) can help.